# NgRx effect mergeMap approach

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, mergemap

I have two implementations of the same effect, and both work. I'm having a hard time understanding the differences between the two and which is more "correct".

Please find them below:

Option 1. IDE cannot figure out the type for `instance` in the last `map`.

```js
    pollingStarted$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(pollingStarted),
            mergeMap(action => action.instances),
            map(instance => performRequest({ instance }))
        )
    );
```

Option 2. All types work out and make sense. This is more correct to me but I want to figure out and understand the differences.

```js
   pollingStarted$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(pollingStarted),
            mergeMap(({ instances }) =>
                instances.map(instance => performRequest({ instance }))
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Great question. I wish I'd done it before, it would have saved me a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the first approach should not work:

```
pollingStarted$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(pollingStarted),
        mergeMap(action => action.instances),
        map(instance => performRequest({ instance }))
    )
);
```

`mergeMap` in this case flats your array, and `map` returns an Observablve for each emitted value. At the end you get an Observable of Observables (`Observable<Observable<your type>>`). You need to use one of [Higher Order Observables](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) instead of `map` to make it working.

Second option is the right one:

```
pollingStarted$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(pollingStarted),
        mergeMap(({ instances }) =>
           instances.map(instance => performRequest({ instance }))
        )
     )
 );
```

`mergeMap` in this case merges an array of observables produced by `instances.map` into a single observable. 
The benefit of using this approach is that you have control over observables, you can apply `catchError` to each `performRequest` or apply it on a higher level after `mergeMap` to have a single error handling for all `performRequest` calls.

Comment: The first does work as far as I can tell. Your explanation of the second is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good guide [here](https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-best-practices-in-angular/) of good and bad practices.

Consider your second example. What if you wanted to add anothe map in your second map?

```
   pollingStarted$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(pollingStarted),
            mergeMap(({ instances }) =>
                instances.map(instance => performRequest({ 
                    instance.map(() => { // And another map})
                }))
            )
        )
    );
```

This would very soon make your code undreadable. What about error handling?

In your first example, you can add just one catchError, that would apply for all maps. In the second case, you woul need to do an error handlind for each map you are having there.

> ```
>     // VERY BAD: nesting subscribes is ugly and takes away
>     // the control over a stream
> ```

The same applies to maps, and any other operator that should be piped. The pipe operator is the equivalent of linux pipe |, and is considered a best practice. It provides cleaner code.

It might  not make sense for just a couple of them, but when it gets nested in multiple levels, it gets very nasty and the code becomes unreadable.

I've recently did a refactoring to get state 2 to look like one in a big project, so that I can manage the code better.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will point out that the inner maps you're referring to are not the rxjs pipeable map operator, but a simple map operation on an array. Also, I'm wondering if you might know why the typechecking for the first option doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly is happening in the first vs second? The second has one less observable than the first, which in my opinion is better.

Comment: Which one is the second observable? They both have exactly the same.

Comment: In the first example mergeMap will combine all the instances and return one observable with multiple emissions. The map right after it will then return one observable for each one of those emissions

Comment: Whereas, the second example simply returns one observable that emits multiple times.